# Creating an emulator for Galaxy S8? - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, screen, galaxy, screen-density

I create a new hardware profile in an attempt to make and emulator for the Galaxy S8/S8+. I set the screen size to 5.8/6.2 inches (depending on whether S8 or S8+, despite the fact this doesn't appear to affect emulator anyway), and the screen resolution to 1440 x 2960, like the device. The emulator appears nothing like it does on the real device. Testing my app on a real S8+ shows it to be laid out poorly, but on the emulator it appear to be relatively organised, and I noticed it uses the dimens for my Nexus 6 emulator (xxxhdpi). Now the dimens values used isn't a big deal, because I'm happy to phase out the Nexus 6 considering it's no longer in production.

So I add some code to my launcher Java class that that gets me the dimensions of the emulator, here is what I get from my S8 emulator: `{density=3.5, width=1440, height=2792, scaledDensity=3.5, xdpi=560.0, ydpi=560.0}`
Besides the fact the height says 2792 instead of 2960 (I assume this is meant to happen), I believe I see the issue - the density is 3.5. As suspected, this is the same density as the Nexus 6. So the emulator I'm creating is not for the Galaxy S8, and this is evident in my comparison to a real S8+ which displayed my app in a distorted manner. As far as I'm aware, the Galaxy S8 has a density of 4, not 3.5. The IDE says the device has 560dpi. Now I need to be able to create an emulator with a density of 4, and the same specs I've already put down. How can I do this? How can I test for the Galaxy S8 without using the real thing? There isn't a preconfigured emulator for this device provided by the IDE.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you help me to understand if there is the way to create a different layout res dir for S8? Because in my case I have a screen that is looks good, but on S8 device all views take their place and a lot of space left up to the bottom. So if there is a way to create res dir as well as `layout-landscape`?

Comment: I'm also having similar issues on s8. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I have got the same issue. If you got the solution, please add it below.

Answer (score 28):

There is no preconfigured emulator. As per my experience, even if you try to create with matching device configuration it won't be much of use as it will still run stock android.

So, I found that Samsung provides online test lab like firebase.

You can go to http://developer.samsung.com/rtlLanding.do and check it out. They give 5 minutes free if you don't have developer account.

As per Samsung, you can get the following:

> - 20 credits are provided to each Samsung Developer user every day.
> - With 1 credit, users can use the Remote Test Lab service for 15    minutes.
> - Minimum reservation: 30 minutes (2 credits)
> - Maximum reservation: 10 hours a day (40 credits)

More details : http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlAboutRTL.action

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, but unfortunately this doesn't allow me to actually view changes I make to my app unless I update it. I can't preview how it looks, like with the emulators in Android Studio. Your post is much appreciated regardless, and I attempted your suggested to provide you with this response, so I have given your answer a positive rating. Hopefully we'll get a proper solution, because so far it seems like the only way to make this work is by using a physical device.

Comment: I keep getting the error "We’re sorry, the requested URL is no longer available :
/home.do" when I go to their website to try to sign up https://developer.samsung.com/home.do

Comment: Direct link to sign up ---> https://program.developer.samsung.com/sign-in

Comment: @kevando that was a great advise. Just to add, Cloud Device Farm that was previously used as Samsung device emulator will be discontinued on Oct 3, 2019 and another service Remote Test Lab will take its place.

Comment: Does this enable debugging or only running the app for testing purposes