# How does Genymotion emulate non Google Devices?

Tags: android, genymotion, galaxy

I'm looking into ways to emulate a Galaxy S8 for android development.  One path of interest is Genymotion.  I've found that they have Galaxy S8 listed as a device, but my understanding is that ["you can't emulate a galaxy s8."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306935/creating-an-emulator-for-galaxy-s8-android-studio)

[image]

So what does Genymotion do?  Is it just a basic emulation with a skin?  Or have they put in some extra work to get a more accurate result?

Comment: i think this is a very interesting question, but i'm not sure if you'll actually be able to get an answer for it

Comment: I don't need to know exactly how to do it, but any amount of information would be nice.  I don't want to pay for the same emulator I run locally with a galaxy skin, if that's their solution.

Comment: i hear you, i've never needed to used genymotion before, but it would be really interesting to know how they create custom devices, hope you find an answer :)